# IE9+ is messing up my JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I was furious when i could not figure out why my app was working fine in Chrome but not IE. After hours of looking at my back end making sure my JSON was coming through to each browser correctly, I noticed this.

In Chrome the JSON object is parsed fine, except in IE9+ it added QUOTES around my Array!
Here is the complete ajax call

```
var jsonTop = [];
var jsonBot = [];

$.when(
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:999/empleplrestop',
        success: function(dataTop) {
            jsonTop = dataTop;
        }
    }), 
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:999/empleplresbot',
        success: function(dataBot) {
            jsonBot = dataBot;
        }   
    })
).then(function() {
    loadTable();
});
```

As you can see, at the success: function(dataTop/Bot) is where it is adding it.

but in IE the JSON object requested through the AJAX was perfectly fine!
(its just mock data)

Am I using $.when wrong? The Quotes are messing up my array!

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/27Xq2Cr.jpg Pic of the JSON object

Comment: what do you expect? You didn't tell the ajax call that you're expecting JSON, so jquery won't parse it for you. It'll just be treated like any **OTHER** plaintext string.

Comment: I don't see how the quotes can possibly be 'messing up your array' given that they are required for valid JSON.

Comment: Roy, The Quotes were messing up, the Answer Barmar supplied was sufficient. I had originally had datatype json but I was using that to  diagnose another issue with it which didnt help so I removed it for some reason or the other.

But thank you Marc B also. Sorry guys for wasting your time, but I am glad you guys pointed it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the `dataType:` option to specify that the result is JSON:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:999/empleplrestop',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(dataTop) {
        jsonTop = dataTop;
    }
}),
```

Comment: What surprises me is that it doesn't fail the same way in Chrome.

Comment: Most web developers assume the worst of IE. So when something works in non-IE and fails in IE, it's natural to assume the problem is in IE, not their code.

Comment: It did surprise me that it didnt fail the same way in chrome mostly because the app that I built that reads jsonTop and jsonBot just fails spectacularly in IE but Chrome still loads the objects fine. Sometimes you spend too long staring at code and the easiest thing staring you in the face is the culprit. I wasnt blaming IE either, if you read my original post, I merely stated what IE was doing, adding quotes to my array? Why? I dont know, it could have been IE, it could have been some code, but it was the AJAX call.

Comment: Are you going to the same server in both cases? The difference could be whether the server sends `Content-type: application/json` in the response.

Comment: My headers are all correct and yes same server, I originally had an issue where IE-9 wouldnt read charset=utf8 but it had to be charset=utf-8. Since then I've made sure all my headers on JSON were coming back fine so I dont have more of those problems. Im pretty new to programming and more so making it work in IE so all these little stuff like dashes in UTF-8 failing in IE9 or specifying specific types where I was absolutely SPOILED by chrome, are biting me in the ass hard for not knowing things properly.